# access vba code returns empty recordset despite table having records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this code in VBA but its returning an empty recordset...

```
Sub total_disc()


Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset


Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("pre_pl")

rst.MoveFirst
```

Where pre_pl is a table with more than a million records. Despite that I am getting rst = nothing.

Any ideas what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way are you able to tell that rst=nothing?  Throw in `MsgBox rst.RecordCount` just after your `rst.MoveFirst` and see what you get.  Because I copy and pasted your code, replace the name with one of my tables and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the size of the table. The limit on table in Access is 2GB, while the limit for a recordset is only 1GB. if you have millions of records, and a lot of data in each record you might be over the limit of a recordset, but not the table. Try creating a query to limit your data to narrower search and see if it works then.

Access Limits can be found here:
https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854#__toc296343505

Comment: I was apparently over the limit for the recordset despite the table being OK.... Thanks for the help!